# Angular JS Grid UI - Create buttons based on column Name == "BUTTON"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am very new to `UI` development and learning AngularJS. I have some ready-made code where I need to make changes to AngularJS UI Grid. My column names are coming dynamically for grid and whenever there is a column called `button`, I needed to create file selector (`input type='file'`) in that column. How do I do that? Please help out.

Comment: BTW, I was referring to this problem but my problem is slightly different than that: http://plnkr.co/edit/8x5pBg3eR6yBHsQcGBDp?p=preview

Comment: any response here?